# Select Features by Polygon - Not Displaying the Shape Drawn

Tags: qgis

I am a relative newbie to QGIS 1.8, have looked through the previous answers, but have found nothing that resolves my issue.

I have a number of datazones as polygons on a layer.  One of the datazones contains two islands that I need to split.  With the layer selected and visible, editing turned on, I choose Select Features by Polygon.  I click on a point in the sea around the island, move my mouse to another point, click again, a line appears, repat this until I get to the point where I want to put the last dot and right click.  What I understand should happen at this point is that a filled shape should appear, but it doesn't, although the islands become selected.

Is this a bug or am I missing something obvious?  The same is true of all of the vector layers from other shapefiles.

Thanks a lot

Andy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I understand you correctly.....

It sounds like you are achieving what you set out to- that is to select the relevant features in your shapefile. Are you needing then to make the selected features into a new shapefile?

You do that by selecting the points as described, right clicking the layer in the table of contents and do "Save selection as", you can then add this back into your map, I sometimes have to tell QGIS what CRS the new layer has before it shows in the right place.

The select tool wont add anything new in itself, you have to go through the additional steps to generate your clipped shapes.